# In Xcode, how do I switch branches, merge changes, and choose which changes to merge?

Tags: swift, xcode, git, github, branch

I'm quite new to Xcode, and I wanted to figure out version control before I added a change that could possibly screw up my project. I'm working on this project alone and have a Git repository saved on my mac, so I don't think I need to link it with a GitHub account. I right-clicked, selected "branch from master", and called it morePictures because of the changes I wanted to make. Now all of the code I have in 'ViewController.swift' has moved to morePictures and when I look at it it shows the master having the none of my code in it with morePictures having all of it. It shows the changes and I'm pretty sure that I have to select to keep or discard certain changes but I don't know how.

In summary, I just want to be able to keep my working code on a master branch, switch between branches, and be able to choose changes to keep and discard when I merge the two.

Here are some pictures of what it looks like now:

[image: master branch]

[image: morePictures branch]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend doing it in the terminal, but if you never used git in the terminal it might be better using Xcode's UI.

## #1 Terminal

First make sure, that all of your changes are committed.
Then you have to go to your project folders.
`cd Your/Project/Directory`
or write `cd`  and drag and drop your you project folder.
Then you have to check on which branch you are on.

`git status`

If you are already on branch master everything is fine, else you have to change your branch to master:

`git checkout master`

Now you can merge your branches:

`git merge morePictures`

That's it!

## #2 Xcode

If you feel more comfortable using Xcode's UI, you can do it like this:

First make sure, that all of your changes are committed, then you can right-click the master branch and select `Checkout...`

[image: Image Checkout]
Now you have to confirm the checkout.

You current Branch is now 'master'.

Next you can right-click your second branch and select `Merge ... into ...`

[image: Image Merge]

Confirm that again and you branch master should be up to data!

Comment: Does the "M" beside the file stand for "Modified"? If that's the case, does it mean that it's not committed? When I tried to commit it got me to select a file, and the only option is 'xcdebugger'. Should I select this and commit it?

Comment: Yes, the 'M’ does indeed stand for Modified. It’s you choice if you want the contents of the file also on the master branch. I’m not quite sure, but it may contain some exp.: Breakpoint Data, which might be useful on the master branch too, so I would commit it.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. So, when I'm coding, I can commit changes to a branch, be it the master or any others, and this is like saving it. Then I can merge the others into the master branch to basically replace the master branch with the branch I'm merging. Before I asked this question I watched this video of an older version of Xcode: https://youtu.be/R_rssimeQ0I (7:06) where you can switch different changes on and off. How do you do that here? There is a panel that compares the code, but I don't see those switches.

Comment: With pressing the 'Merge' button, the panel with the switches should appear automatically. Unfortunately I don't know what to do if the panel doesn't appear as it should and even on my machine it's not working as intended. Maybe this extensive tutorial about Git Source Control with Xcode 9 could help you: https://www.raywenderlich.com/675-how-to-use-git-source-control-with-xcode-9